# Android Studio 2.0: Run task only on first run. NOT at Instant Run

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-gradle-2.0

I'm trying to setup instant runt for my project. Unfortunately my predecessors decided to hook some actions to preBuild (downloading configuration data to be more precise). The actions provide some data to BuildConfig. This is being run now every time I try to use the Instant Run feature and makes it ~1,5min long.

My question is: Is there a way to hook a task only to the dry run and do not run it for Instant Run?

**First run:**

1. downloadingTask
2. prebuild and stuff

**Instant run:**

1. prebuild and stuff

Comment: There was [a related discussion on the `adt-dev` Google Group yesterday](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/rgZNYDL5_A8) that might help, though I haven't played with the approach personally.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, i'll check it out!

Comment: You can also disable instant run if you don't want it

Comment: @VivekMishra i want it, that's why im searching for some info how to work around my issue